# on Click not working after hitting back button in single page app

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I am having trouble with my onClick event.
I am adding the HTML to the DOM via DOM insertion during/after pageload.
The page I am dealing with is a single page application.

When the page first loads, my on click event works fine.  When I navigate to the next page within the SPA and then click the back button to go back to the original page, the onClick doesn't work.

I've tried setTimeout and polling and nothing has worked.  The onclick will work if I paste it into the Google console, but won't work on load.  I am not quite sure why setTimeout and polling isn't working.

```
//css

.hideIt{display:none;}

//html
<div class="optMbPriceContainer">
  <div class="optMbBaseRow">
   <span class="">Base Price</span>
   <span class="right">$91.79</span>
   <span class="right optMbStrikethruPrice">$101.99</span>
  </div>
 <div class="optMbTaxesRow2">
   <span class="optShowTaxDetails2">Taxes &amp; Fees</span>
   <span class="right">$40.36</span>
   <div class="optTaxDetails2 hideIt" style="">
     <div class="optTaxParent2"><!--taxes go here--></div>
   </div><
 /div>
<div class="optMbTotalRow">
  <span class="optEstTotalTxt">Estimated Total (Prepaid)</span>
  <span class="pull-right">$132.15</span></div>
<div class="optTotalSavings">
  <span class="">Total Savings</span>
  <span class="pull-right optTotalSavingsAmt">$10.20</span>
</div>
</div>



//jquery
angular.element(document).on('click', '.optShowTaxDetails2', function() {
  $('.optTaxDetails2').toggleClass('hideIt');
});
```

Comment: I've never used Angular, but isn't that piece of JS code you posted executed at every page load (i.e. when you go to another page via navigation)? If that is the case, you would be adding a new on-click callback every time you navigate between pages. Thus the `toggleClass()` would be executed multiple times on each click. If its executed an even number of times, the element's state (shown/hidden) would appear not to be chaning.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký Your comment sparked a thought.  I notice that when I navigate back to the original page, the hideIt class isn't removed onClick, so your point sounds correct.  Any thought on how I can prevent that from happening?  Maybe removing the original on navigating to another page?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my original implementation of on click was binding it to the document rather than the element, which is why it was being added every time I navigated back to the page.  Instead I used:

```
 $('.optShowTaxDetails').click(function () {
                 $('.optTaxDetails').toggleClass('hide');
            });
```